AWS Glue ETL Filter Transformation not returning expected results
Using Glue ETL UI version 4.0 and I want to use the Filter transformation to remove any blank records based on a selected field. The field is a type string but it's has a datetime field. Format is 2023-10-21T00:35:01.000+0000 . I have also tried other string column to filter with no success.
The operation for the filter is "matches" (Matches is only logic operation for type string). I've tried these regex ^.+ and  ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\S+ and \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}[+\-]\d{4}$` and a couple other regex, but the filter returns zero (0) rows.  One suggestion was to use double \ , tested and returned no records.
Cheers
